# Grid Not populating in kendoGrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, kendo-ui

I am using MVC 4  and kendo UI for grid population. But the grid is not populating correctly.

this is my View :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Employee_Read", "UserSummary")',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: "json",
            Async: true,
            success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                var dataloc = data;



                var element = $("#grid4").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: {
                        data: dataloc,
                        schema: {
                            model: {
                                fields: {
                                    userDetailsId: { type: "number", editable: false },
                                    name: { type: "string", editable: false },
                                    roleId: { type: "string", editable: false },
                                    emailId: { type: "string", editable: false }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Conroller ;

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Employee_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        using (var emp = new MockProjectAkarshEntities1())
        {
          IQueryable<tbl_UserDetails> userDetails = emp.tbl_UserDetails;


            DataSourceResult result = userDetails.ToDataSourceResult(request);

            return Json(result,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


        }
```

In the output I am getting something like "[object][object]" and no of rows in the table returned from database.the skeleton of grid is coming but not the data. I am new to MVC and kendo. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you received should be started with `{"Data":` So simply change your code from `var dataloc = data;` to `var dataloc = data.Data;` just confirm it by visiting UserSummary/Employee_Read.

You can also set the dataSource later on like this (if you prefer at some stage)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Employee_Read", "UserSummary")',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    Async: true,
    success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
        var dataloc = data.Data;
        var element = $("#grid4").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                // data: dataloc,
                schema: {
                        model: {
                            fields: {
                                userDetailsId: { type: "number", editable: false },
                                name: { type: "string", editable: false },
                                roleId: { type: "string", editable: false },
                                emailId: { type: "string", editable: false }
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        // create data source using the data received  
        var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                        data: dataloc
                     });
        $('#grid4').data('kendoGrid').setDataSource(ds);
    }
});
</script>
```